# Phone (Nexus Zenfone 5 !!MODEL ZE620KL!!) only boots into TWRP

Tags: twrp, bootloader

So I unlocked my bootloader and flashed twrp, but my data was auto-encrypted so i had to perform a wipe from inside twrp. I did this and now everytime i start my phone it boots into twrp. I tried flashing a custom rom but i dont think my version of twrp has usb support since i couldnt tick the box. 
So tbh im not sure if i accidentally deleted my stock version of android or if i just did something else wrong, and its very hard to find information about this since theres another phone by the exact same name (ASUS Zenfone 5) but the one I have has the model number (ZE620KL).

So yeah how do I make my phone boot into android instead of twrp everytime i turn it on.

Comment: Does the vol-up/down keys work correctly in TWRP?

Comment: they dont do anything, i dont think theyre supposed to do anything since theres a sound setting in the twrp settings

Comment: Originally a recovery ROMs were using the volume buttons for up/down navigation. That nowadays TWRP supports to use the touch screen is often a convenience function. Because if one of the volume buttons would be defect and permanently firing "I am pressed" the system may always boot into recovery even if the main OS is present. That would be one possible explanation for your problem.

Comment: you probably wiped wrong partition. `fastboot boot boot.img` will ignore volume keys (in case button stucks)

Comment: click on [Show all](https://www.asus.com/Phone/ZenFone-5-ZE620KL/HelpDesk_BIOS) and download proper version, try oldest first

Comment: ok but how do i download it only my device? adb via usb doesnt seem to be working

Comment: flash with QFIL (or what i would do: `python sdat2img.py vendor.transfer.list vendor.new.dat` and `adb push vendor.img /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/vendor` and same for `system.new.dat`. **adb is working in twrp.** `boot.img` can be flashed from fastboot in download/bootloader mode directly too)

Comment: https://www.firmware27.com/2018/03/asus-zenfone-5-5z-firmware.html